# Ajax paging is duplicating _layout page while using pagination to replace page content

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using [x.PagedList](https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList) to use pagination in my ASP.NET MVC page. The only problem I have with the plugin is , it used a page refresh when I navigate between pages.

To avoid that I am using jQuery calls to replace page contents as explained in this [article](http://www.lybecker.com/blog/2014/09/29/ajax-paging-for-asp-net-mvc-sites/).

My View and javascript looks like this.

```
<div id="circuitsContent">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            --Header 
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                --Loop through and create content
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
</div>

<div id="circuitContentPager">
    @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model, page => Url.Action("Circuits", new { page }))
</div>

@section scripts
{
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on("click", "#circuitContentPager a[href]", function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr("href"),
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#circuitsContent').html(result);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
 </script>
```

And this is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult Circuits(int? page)
        {

            var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
            var circuits = _repo.GetAllCircuits().OrderBy(circ=>circ.ID).ToList();
            var pagedCircuits = circuits.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 25);


            return View(pagedCircuits);
        }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: For a start, you should be return a `PartialViewResult`, not a `ViewResult`

Comment: There are other issues with your code as well - you need a different method to return the results (not the same method that renders the initial view), so that the partial renders only the html for the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax call returns the html from `Circuits()` method which is the same view you have used to render the page initially, which includes all the initial html, but you only replacing part of of the existing page, so elements such as the paging buttons generated by the `@Html.PagedListPager()` method are going to be repeated. Your also generating invalid html because of duplicate `id` attributes (you will have multiple `<div id="circuitsContent">` elements

There are 2 ways you could solve this.

Create a separate controller method that returns a partial view of just the `<table>` and call that method, however you would need to extract the value of the page number for the `href` attribute of you pager buttons to pass that as well.

Using your current `Circuits()` method, test if the request is ajax, and if so, return a partial view of just the `<table>`.

```
public ActionResult Circuits(int? page)
{
    var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
    var circuits = _repo.GetAllCircuits().OrderBy(circ=>circ.ID);
    var pagedCircuits = circuits.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 25);
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest)
    {
        return PartialView("_Circuits", pagedCircuits);
    }
    return View(pagedCircuits);
}
```

Note: Do not use `.ToList()` in your query. That is defeating the whole purpose of using server side paging because `.ToList()` immediately downloads all the records fro the database.

Where `_Circuits.cshtml` would be

```
@model IEnumerable<yourModel>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            // <th> elements
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
            .... // Loop through and create content
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that your header elements should be in a `<thead>` element and the records in a `<tbody>` element.

Comment: This works but now the active page does not change to the new one. Even if I change navigate to page 4 , the active page remains on page 1!! Updated the question new value...

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you mean that when you click on the 'page 6' button it is only returning the results for page 1? (if so check that your actually getting a value for the `page` parameter in the controller method)

Comment: OK, just seen your edit. You would need some javascript to set the relevant class name of the button you just clicked (sorry, I cant remember what that is but if you inspect the page source I'm sure you will find it)

Comment: @Simsons,I rolled back your edit because its not related to your question (you would only be getting that behavior is you implemented my answer so it makes no sense in the context of the question). Just a guess, but I assume it would be `active` so you would need `$(document).on("click", "#circuitContentPager a[href]", function () { $(this).addClass('active') ...`, but you would also need to keep track of the current button, so you can remove that class from it when you click another button (I don't have `PagedList` installed on this device so can't test it just now)

Comment: I tried adding class active after your first comment but it is not working. Currently all buttons are as , li and the one active is ,<li class="active"><span>1</span></li> where as the ones are not active is <li><a href="/Home/Circuits?page=4">4</a></li>. So trying to find parent and add class. Also as you rightly mentioned need to keep track of these as well...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163452/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-simsons).